# something better than base64 to encode data that doesn't take up too much processing power

Tags: javascript

I have a web site in which users can add multiple items and sometimes the URL can be long. I thought by using base64 encoding, I'd pass the URL along but it contains a slash which I use to separate items because my web server cannot handle path names (anything between 2 slashes) longer than 255 characters or I'd get a 403 error.

Is there another way I can encode data quickly in javascript so that theres a 0% chance that a slash will occur in the result?

I'm looking for something not too processor intensive and if possible, I want to go for something better than character swapping.

I will understand if I need to visit a library, but the only encoding built-in to javascript (to my knowledge) is base64 (via the atob function) and I want something different.

I also want to be able to make the solution work with older web browsers as well.

Comment: What's the data you're encoding, and why not character swapping?

Comment: Why is your url long? Are you passing the data in the query string or as a path?

Comment: Show us an example of a long URL.

Comment: Data is passed as part of the url. in the form of http://example.com/someextension/(insert-encoded-data-here-for-product)/(insert-encoded-data-here-for-another-product)/...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to maintain the state of something like a shopping cart in the URL. That's too much state for a URL, and better suited to session handling. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mike - probably an indicator that POST would be a better option than GET for the mechanism of passing the data back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to address this but one of the simplest is going to be to take an implementation of `atob` and `btoa` and modify it to use a `-` instead of a `/` when encoding. You'll have to rename the functions so they don't mask the standard function, but here's some JavaScript source code that does the trick: [github](https://gist.github.com/sevir/3946819). In that particular implementation just replace the `/` in `_ALPHA` with a `-` (or any character of your choosing).

It might be faster to just do as Amit suggests: use the standard functions and do a quick string replace of `/` on conversion: `str.replace(/\//g,'-');` and perform the reverse on decoding, but it doesn't seem like performance will be critical in this application.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because I used your suggestion. I also was fortunate enough to find a library for base64 encoding that might work in Internet Explorer. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/base64.js

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [encodeURIComponent](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/encodeuricomponent), which is part of the javascript spec and automatically included in all javascript environments

```
var url = 'example.com/someextenstion/' + encodeURIComponent(theString);
```